# Shortest number of steps to reach a position

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

I'm on an infinite number line. I start at 0 and at each step can move to the left or to the right. At the $n$'th step my step length is n.

So my motion can be $1$ move to the right, $2$ moves to the left and then $3$ moves to the right.

What is the minimum number of steps required to reach $n$-th position?

I'm looking for closed form solutions - I've realised that it is always possible to reach the $n$-th position in atmost $2n-1$ moves where $n>0$ and $-2n$ moves where $n<0$. How do I get a closed form?

I tried to formulate the problem as a recurrence relation, where $f(n):\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$ is the minimum number of steps needed to reach the $n$-th position and ended up with this $$f(n\pm f(n))=f(n)-1$$ where  the $\pm$ means that it's sometimes plus and sometimes minus. This may seem to be rubbish to you, but this is all I could do.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that $f(n)=k-1$ implies $f(n\pm k)=k$. One small such example is $f(6)=3=4-1$ so we have $n=6,k=4$, but $f(6-4)=f(2)=3\neq 4$. The reason is that $2=1-2+3$ is simpler than $2=1+2+3-4$. Note that the first part $-1=1-2$ of the optimal solution for $n=2$ is in fact not optimal, since for that case $-1=-1$ is simpler. So it appears that working recursively does not get us anywhere. And checking all possibilities grows exponentially with the number of steps we allow, so it is hard to verify optimal solutions for a maximal number of steps $k$ of even a moderate size.

Comment: @String so what you're saying is that there's no closed form possible?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is tabulated out to $n=100$ at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A140358). There's a conjecture there:

Choose $k$ so that $t(k)\le n<t(k+1)$ where $t(n)$ is the $n$-th triangular number $t(n)=n(n+1)/2$. If $n=t(k)$, $a(n)=k$, otherwise if $k$ is odd then $a(n)=k+2$ if $n-t(k)$ is odd, $a(n)=k+1$ if $n-t(k)$ is even, else if $k$ is even than $a(n)=k+1$ if $n-t(k)$ is odd, $a(n)=k+3$ if $n-t(k)$ is even. (This has been verified for $n$ up to 100.)

At [this](http://oeis.org/A140358/b140358.txt) page, it is tabulated out to $n=10,000$.

Comment: When $n=t(k)$ this conjecture must be true for that part. For the cases $a(n)=k+1$ it must also be true, if the conjecture is constructive and points to specific solutions with $k+1$ steps for those $n$'s. If the conjecture IS indeed constructive it seems extremely likely to be true!