# Reach N from $0$ in the least number of moves where the n'th move comprises of n steps and each step is a $\pm 1$ movement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Reach the number $\text{N}$ from $0$ in the least number of moves where the $n\text{th}$ move comprises of $n$ many steps and each step is a $\pm 1$ movement. The same problem also exists [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008999/shortest-number-of-steps-to-reach-a-position) without a proof.

Suppose $k$ is the largest number such that $S :=1 + 2 + \cdots + k \leq \text{N}$. If it equals $\text{N}$ we are done and if the distance left after going from $S$ to $N$ is even, we are still done (and our answer will be $k+1$) since we can then repetitively go back from $N$ to $\text{N}-1$ and back to $\text{N}$ in an even number of steps. Now if the distance left is odd, we do the exact same thing, and depending on the parity of $k$, the answer will be $k+2$ or $k+3$. But the point is, when the distance left $(k+1 - (N - S))$ is odd, I do not have a good enough reasoning to conclude that "it" is the answer. **I only have that as the upper-bound and $k+1$ the lower bound, nothing more.**

Rewrite every move $j$ as $a_j + b_j = j$ (both non-negative) such that the problem can be re-written as :
**Find the least $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum(a_j) + \sum(b_j) = N$  subject to $0 \leq \max(|a_j|, |b_j|) \leq j$.**

May I get a solid proof for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remaining case is that all the following are true:

1. $S:= 1 + 2 + \cdots + k < N$,
2. $S+(k+1) > N$ and
3. $S+(k+1) - N$ is odd

Condition $3$ means $S+(k+1)$ and $N$ are in different parity,

$$S+(k+1) \not\equiv N \pmod 2$$

and so the minimum number of moves is strictly greater than $k+1$.

Then there are two cases depending on the parity of $k+2$:

---

If $k+2\equiv 0 \pmod 2$, then

$$S+(k+1)+(k+2)\not\equiv N\pmod 2$$

so the minimum number of moves is still strictly greater than $k+2$. But considering the $(k+3)$th move,

$$\begin{align*}
(k+2)+(k+3) &\equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
S+(k+1)+(k+2)+(k+3) &\equiv N
\end{align*}$$

Otherwise if $k+2 \equiv 1\pmod 2$, then

$$S+(k+1)+(k+2) \equiv N \pmod 2$$

---

This shows that the minimum number of moves that matches the parity of $N$ is $k+2$ or $k+3$ (depending on the parity of $k$), and this rejects $k+1$ as the answer.